# Get fully qualified name of Python function without executing the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I am writing a library to help me visualize some metrics of my own code. This led me to need a fully qualified name of any function call in the code that I am analyzing.

I had hoped that using Python's [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module would provide me this. If I walk the tree, it does provide the nodes for any imports and aliases, and it does provide the nodes for the actual function calls.

However, trying to build the fully qualified name from these nodes is not an easy task and I doubt it would handle all situations. How should I go about doing this? (My IDE supports Go To Definition so I know this is possible.)

---

Here is a prettyprint of a function call node, note the name is not the full name:

```
Call(func=Name(id='fib', ctx=Load()), args=[
    Num(n=100),
  ], keywords=[])
```